# How to start linux with gui without monitor?

Tags: linux, screen, x11, monitor, xorg

I met a problem.
I had a server which is installed redhat enterprise 5.5.
And one Qt program was running on this server.
So what I should do is to turn on my server, the server will start automaticly with Gui and that Qt program will start automaticly.
I finished all on my desktop.
But while I start this server without monitor, we know server was running without monitor,the X server go bad.God, what should I do?

Here is the xorg log:

```
[root@localhost grub]# tail -n 30 /var/log/Xorg.0.log
ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 1.0
(II) Loading sub module "i2c"
(II) LoadModule: "i2c"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libi2c.so
(II) Module i2c: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
compiled for 7.1.1, module version = 1.2.0
ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 1.0
(II) intel(0): Output VGA has no monitor section
(II) intel(0): I2C bus "CRTDDC_A" initialized.
(II) intel(0): EDID for output VGA
(II) intel(0): Output VGA disconnected
(WW) intel(0): No outputs definitely connected, trying again...
(II) intel(0): Output VGA disconnected
(WW) intel(0): Unable to find initial modes
(EE) intel(0): No valid modes.
(II) UnloadModule: "intel"
(II) UnloadModule: "i2c"
(II) Unloading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libi2c.so
(II) UnloadModule: "ddc"
(II) Unloading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libddc.so
(II) UnloadModule: "vgahw"
(II) Unloading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvgahw.so
(II) UnloadModule: "vbe"
(II) Unloading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
(II) UnloadModule: "int10"
(II) Unloading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
(EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
Fatal server error:
no screens found
```

I searched on internet,somebody told me that I should add nomodeset in the end of the kernel line in /boot/grub/grub.conf.I did it but nothing changed.
Can anybody tell me what should I do?

smarthand123@163.com

Comment: Try specifying `i915.modeset=0` in the kernel command line. See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1292212 for details.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!My friend!But I am using Redhat Enterprise 5.5,not ubuntu.According to "add i915.modest=0 to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub",I find nothing in /etc/default on redhat.What shall I do?

Comment: Try `/etc/grub.conf`, the kernel command line should be there IIRC.

Comment: Thank you very much!Tomorrow I will try it according to what you wrote.Good night!My friend.

Comment: Hi,my friend.I added `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT = "quiet"`to /etc/default/grub,then I added `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT = "915.modest=0"` to /etc/default/grub.I also added `i915.modeset=0` to /etc/grub.conf and /boot/grub/grub.conf.After doing all,I reboot my desktop without monitor,but X did not go well.Here is my `lspci | grep VGA` output `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)`.Thank you for helping me!My friend!

Comment: If this is for your home server, you can buy some fake hdmi plug. Search "Virtual Display Adaper" in google, you should find some products for your need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that the X server checks whether there is really a monitor attached. Your options:

1. Attach a monitor. Simple but wasteful.
2. Use Xvnc instead. This is like X but it renders to memory, so it doesn't need a graphics card (and no drivers) and no monitor. You can even connect to it remotely via the VNC protocol.

The second option is actually pretty simple to implement: Just call `vncserver :42`

After `export DISPLAY=:42`, you can run your Qt application and it will connect to the virtual Xvnc server running on the virtual display 42 (0 is the default).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! My good friend!But my customer ask me to place a lot of servers just like it.And I can not use VNC bucause it it not connect to internet.By the way,there are so many servers that I can not use vnc to connect server one by one.God,what should I do?

Comment: He didn't say you had to *connect* to the VNC server... just start it.

Comment: You are right.I read Aaron Digulla's topic again.Now I got him,thanks both of you,my friend.

Comment: Thank you very much!I did it follow your topic.Now it went well.

Comment: Now I met another problem,please give me some advise.Thanks![http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715063/why-the-command-in-root-bash-profile-start-twice]

Answer (score 1):

Restart the X server, open a tty window (alt + f1) or (alt+f2) then login on the terminal and run 'startx'. Otherwise try ssh-ing to the server and either attempt startx or reboot the machine.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.But there are so many servers that I can not type startx one by one.By the way,these servers do not connect to internet.

Comment: You don't need the Internet to run ssh or vnc. SSH could also do X forwarding, which allows you to use a window on your workstation as the 'screen' for GUI applications on the server.  As for not wanting to type commands manually, you can simply write a script

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) (x server with virtual framebuffer)

Comment: Hi,my friend.Thank you for helping me!But now these servers will be set in a lot of places.Some place is far away from city,for example,some villages.So to manage these servers through net is impossible.And we must set these servers one by one,from this place to another place.Even the one who will carry server to set is not us.So it is impossible to manage these server myself.God,what shall I do?I am new in this company.Now I met this problem.Please help me,thank you!