# Why the command in /root/.bash_profile start twice?

Tags: linux, redhat, bash

Here is my `/root/.bash_profile`:

```
export DISPLAY=:42 && cd /home/df/SimulatedRpu-ex/bin && ./SimulatedRpu-V1 &
```

When I start my server,I run `ps aux | grep SimulatedRpu` and here is the output:

```
root      2758  0.2  1.0  62316 20416 ?        Sl   14:35   0:00 ./SimulatedRpu-V1
root      3197  0.5  0.9  61428 19912 pts/0    Sl   14:35   0:00 ./SimulatedRpu-V1
root      3314  0.0  0.0   5112   716 pts/0    S+   14:35   0:00 grep SimulatedRpu
```

So,the program print error message about the port is already used.
But why the command in `/root/.bash_profile` start twice?
Please help me,thank you!By the way,I use Redhat Enterprise 5.5

Comment: Try it on separate lines or with ; in between.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!I followed what you said and I fixed this problem.Best wishes for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The profile is read every time you log in. So just by logging in to run the `ps aux | grep SimulatedRpu`, you run the profile once more and thus start a new process.

You should put the command into an [init script](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442412-managing-linux-daemons-with-init-scripts) instead.

**[EDIT]** You should also run `Xvnc` in the same script - that way, you can start and stop the display server together with your app.

Comment: However the init scripts are run before you have even logged in and it looks like he is trying to start an application on a desktop screen.

Comment: Ah ... no, he's running the app on Xvnc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699992/how-to-start-linux-with-gui-without-monitor

Comment: Thanks both of you!My friends!While I saw your hot answers,I feel very happy!Now I used one way to deal with this problem.I set vncserver automaticly start.I set `export DISPLAY=:42 ; cd /home/df/SimulatedRpu-ex/bin && ./SimulatedRpu-V1` in /root/.bash_profile,and I wrote a pdf readme file to send to the engineer,teach them to connect to server using another account through putty.They will open a screen on server,and type sudo su - to switch root,ok,the Qt program will start.

Comment: Unless your application needs root access, then you can install it as any user. Running software as root is always a security risk and VNC is a protocol that can be used for an attack, too.

Comment: Yes,I agreed with you.These servers were running in a special net which do not connect to Internet,they are protected.Now this company knows little about linux,so they emploied me.My first job is to solve this problem.The old staff took linux as windows,they like gui.So they developed a Qt program with gui on linux and wanted it start automaticly.My Previous company taught me to use linux text mode,taught me to run program on server useing another account,I especially like CentOS.But now,I must adjust to the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like

```
if ! ps aux | grep '[S]imulateRpu'; then
    export DISPLAY=:42 && cd /home/df/SimulatedRpu-ex/bin && ./SimulatedRpu-V1 &
fi;
```

This way it will first check if if the application is not running yet. The [] around the S are to prevent grep from finding itself ;)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!I also wrote a shell like what you write.But I ran the Qt program in VNCserver.So it dose not work.Finally,I use another way to deal with this problem.